# Oracle 11g desired output from below table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have below the table in my oracle 11g XE database.

```
COL1            COL2        COL3       COL4         COL5 COL6   COL7  COL8                                                  
Legacy ID       1234                                        
9/1/2022                   25035389    MT           REC  DEU    BGD   123.76
                                       0.558
9/1/2022                   25035390    MT           REC  DEU    BGD   123.76
                                       0.558
9/1/2022                   25035391    MT           REC  DEU    BGD   123.76
                                       0.558
```

My Desired Output should be like below table:

```
COL1            COL2            COL3       COL4    COL5  COL6   COL7 COL8                                                   
Legacy ID       1234                                    
9/1/2022        1234           25035389    MT      REC   DEU    BGD  123.76
9/1/2022        1234           25035389            0.558
9/1/2022        1234           25035390    MT      REC   DEU    BGD  123.76
9/1/2022        1234           25035390            0.558
9/1/2022        1234           25035391    MT      REC   DEU    BGD  123.76
9/1/2022        1234           25035391            0.558
```

How can I get desired output by sql

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; an English description of the logic that generates that output (as result sets have a non-deterministic order so the order of your input is not guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` clause but there is nothing obvious that you would use to order it); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service; **YOU** need to attempt the problem and then we can help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
With your changed sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 'Legacy ID' "COL1", '1234' "COL2", Null     "COL3", Null    "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select '9/1/2022'  "COL1", Null   "COL2", 25035389 "COL3", 'MT'    "COL4", 'REC' "COL5", 'DEU' "COL6", 'BGD' "COL7", '123.76' "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select 'Legacy ID' "COL1", '4567' "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select '9/1/2022'  "COL1", Null   "COL2", 25035390 "COL3", 'MT'    "COL4", 'REC' "COL5", 'DEU' "COL6", 'BGD' "COL7", '123.76' "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select 'Legacy ID' "COL1", '6789'   "COL2", Null   "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select '9/1/2022'  "COL1", Null   "COL2", 25035391 "COL3", 'MT'    "COL4", 'REC' "COL5", 'DEU' "COL6", 'BGD' "COL7", '123.76' "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual Union All
            Select Null        "COL1", Null   "COL2", Null     "COL3", '0.558' "COL4", Null  "COL5", Null  "COL6", Null  "COL7", Null     "COL8" From Dual
        ),
/*
COL1      COL2       COL3 COL4  COL5 COL6 COL7 COL8 
--------- ---- ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---- ------
Legacy ID 1234                                        
9/1/2022         25035389 MT    REC  DEU  BGD  123.76 
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
Legacy ID 4567            0.558                       
9/1/2022         25035390 MT    REC  DEU  BGD  123.76 
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
Legacy ID 6789            0.558                       
9/1/2022         25035391 MT    REC  DEU  BGD  123.76 
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
                          0.558                       
*/
```

Create a CTE to get you row span for COL2 value

```sql
      tbl_2 AS
          (   SELECT
                  COL2, RN_VAL, 
                  CASE WHEN Max(RN_VAL) OVER(Partition By 1 Order By RN_VAL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) = RN_VAL THEN 999999999 
                  ELSE Max(RN_VAL) OVER(Partition By 1 Order By RN_VAL ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) - 1
                  END "SPAN"
              FROM
                  (   Select 
                          COL2 "COL2", 
                          Nvl(Last_Value(COL2) OVER(Order By ROWNUM Rows Between Current Row And 1 Following), First_Value(COL2) OVER(Order By ROWNUM Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)) "NEXT_VAL",
                          CASE WHEN COL2 Is Not Null THEN ROWNUM END "RN_VAL"
                      From 
                          tbl 
                  )
              WHERE RN_VAL Is Not Null
          )
```

Main sql

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.COL1, t2.COL2, t1.COL3, t1.COL4, t1.COL5, t1.COL6, t1.COL7, t1.COL8 
FROM
    (   SELECT
            ROWNUM "RN",
            CASE WHEN t.COL1 Is NULL THEN Min(t.COL1) OVER(Partition By 1 Order By 1 Rows Between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ELSE t.COL1 END "COL1",
            t.COL3 "COL3",
            CASE WHEN t.COL4 = 'MT' THEN t.COL4 END "COL4",
            CASE WHEN t.COL4 = 'MT' THEN t.COL5 ELSE t.COL4 END "COL5",
            t.COL6 "COL6", 
            t.COL7 "COL7",
            t.COL8 "COL8"
        FROM
            tbl t
    ) t1
INNER JOIN
    tbl_2 t2 ON(t1.RN Between t2.RN_VAL And t2.SPAN )
/*  R e s u l t :
COL1      COL2       COL3 COL4  COL5  COL6 COL7 COL8 
--------- ---- ---------- ----- ----- ---- ---- ------
Legacy ID 1234                                         
9/1/2022  1234   25035389 MT    REC   DEU  BGD  123.76 
9/1/2022  1234                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  1234                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  1234                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  1234                  0.558                  
Legacy ID 4567                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  4567   25035390 MT    REC   DEU  BGD  123.76 
9/1/2022  4567                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  4567                  0.558                  
Legacy ID 6789                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  6789   25035391 MT    REC   DEU  BGD  123.76 
9/1/2022  6789                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  6789                  0.558                  
9/1/2022  6789                  0.558                               
*/
```

Comment: Works fine up to 200 rows but after 200 rows for COL3. Can you help?

Comment: @Md.SajjadHussain Yes, I will do my best to help you, but what is happening? Is there an error message? You should tell me what's it all about.

Comment: I have 259 rows of data. After 200 rows of COL3, it always returns the 200th value of COL3.

**** CASE WHEN COL7 IS NULL THEN MAX(COL7) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) ELSE COL7 END "LEGACY_ID" ****

Comment: @Md.SajjadHussain If COL3 in your table is Null the value  returned should be the value from previous row. If it is not null (has a value) then that value should be returned. Could you check a few rowss before row 200 and a few rows after to see if the condition is like explained.

Comment: @Md.SajjadHussain Regarding your COL7 from comment above - it says that if COL7 is null than the value returned shall be the greatest of all rows before this and 2 rows after this one. If it is not null then the current value should be returned. The thing that could be the problem is ORDER BY clause in all CASE expressions. It would be easier if there is a colummn that orders the rows in the right way to do the job. Is there any such column in the table?

Comment: There are several columns in my table.  

**`217 11/7/2022 963216  Account Total: -2650.66 0` 
217 11/7/2022 963216   -2650.66 0 
218 ACN  :  101171539    
218 ACN  :  101171539    
219 11/7/2022 305000     
219 11/7/2022 305000     
220 11/7/2022 963216     
220 11/7/2022 963216     
221 11/7/2022 963216 36047262 AUS -26000.06 547.24 -82.09
221 11/7/2022 963216 36047262 AUS -26000.06 547.24 -82.09
`**

I have taken a few of them.  there is a value at row 219  which is 305000. So in that case, at row 220  the query should have returned 305000 instead of 963216.

Comment: @Md.SajjadHussain You are saying that there are values in both rows 219 and 220 - then in row 220 is value of row 220. If the value of row 220 were NULL then the column would take the value from previous row. If you always want the value from previous row then the CASE should be different try to add in select additional resulting column COL3A like here:  Nvl(FIRST_VALUE(COL3) OVER(Partition By 1 Order By 1 Rows Between 1 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW), COL3) "COL3A",

Comment: The value in Row number 210 (Ex: 1234) and from rows 211 to 219 is null. In row 220 there is another value (Ex: 4567), which is from 221 to 229. I'm trying to fill rows 211 to 219 by the 210th value i.e 1234. After reaching 221th to 229th it should be filled by 4567.

Comment: @Md.SajjadHussain Just updated the answer. It will fill the gaps of COL2 values as you asked.